# Box position not centering

Tags: html, css, centering

Im trying to center a box 200 by 200. I have tried using `left:50% top:50%` etc., but this is somehow not really working.

I created a fiddle to recreate my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/8k9o9Lvv/2/

I also tried to center the text from the top as well, with `text-align:center` and this is also not working.

Any ideas why this is not working?

**HTML**

```html
<div id ="container">
  <div class="slider-text">
    <h2>Test</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#container{
  width:100%;
}

.slider-text {
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-left:1px solid red;
  border-right:1px solid red;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  right:50%;
}
```

Comment: You are using `position: relative` and `top, bottom, left, right`. Change to `position: absolute` and give `container position: relative`

Comment: see: https://jsfiddle.net/zainabr1/8k9o9Lvv/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the below code a try, centering the `#container` div horizontally, and the `.slider-text` div horizontally and vertically within `#container`.

```css
#container{
  width:100%;
}

.slider-text {
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  border:1px solid red; /* Creates a border around entire element */
  margin: auto; /* Centers horizontally */
}

/* This is to center the text vertically within its parent, */
/* remove it if you don't want to do that */
.slider-text h2 {
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute; /* position: relative; works too */
  width: 100%;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">

  <div class="slider-text">
    <h2>Test</h2>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just `margin:0px auto;` is enough

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin:0px auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="slider-text">
    <h2>Test
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Downvoter... Your majesty, tell me what i did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slider-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align:center;
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-left:1px solid red;
  border-right:1px solid red;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  right:50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
  <div class="slider-text">
    <h2>Test</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to set the height of the container. In this case I used 100vh which is equal to 1 viewport height. `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` with `top: 50%; left: 50%` will make your `.slider-text` on center.

To center your text. You can use flexbox. Using display: flex will enable you to use align-items and justify-content. With value of center, it will allow your text to flow on center of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `height:100%` to all elements down to your container. That means:

```
html, body, #container
{
  height:100%;
}
```

Then to center horizontaly and verically a known-size div inside your `#container`, you just need to set for that div:

```
left:50%;
top:50%;
```

**and**

```
margin-left:(MINUS whatever is the half of your div width)
margin-top:(MINUS whatever is the half of your div height)
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8k9o9Lvv/10/) (sorry forgot to "update" it)

edit: i assumed you want to center it to the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML

```
 <div id ="container">
  <div class="slider-text">
    <h2>Test</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Modified CSS

```
#container{
  width:100%;
}
.slider-text {
  position:relative;
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider-text h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container{
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-text {
  text-align:center;
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-left:1px solid red;
  border-right:1px solid red;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

/*since slider-text has a fixed height and width, a simple math would do*/

.slider-text h2 {
 margin-top: 90px;
  }
```

```html
<div id ="container">
<div class="slider-text"><h2>Test
</h2></div>
</div>
```

Just a simple calculation would do

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to center it both X and Y, you're right so far, however there are a few changes. Use this for your `.slider-text` class:

```
.slider-text {
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute; /* Relative was wrong */
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-left:1px solid red;
  border-right:1px solid red;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Relative positioning was incorrect in this instance. `absolute` is correct. Relative would make it move X amount of pixels from its natural position, whereas absolute will position it in a specific place, relative to the closest parent with `position: relative` on it.

The transform basically does the same as negative margins, but you don't need to change the margin if the size of the box changes :)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css code:

```
.slider-text {
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-left:1px solid red;
  border-right:1px solid red;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-100px;
  margin-top:-100px;
}
```

margin-left:-(div width)/2;
      margin-top:-(div height)/2;